# What does it mean that Gintoki and his friends are "Yorozuya"?

Tags: japanese-language, gintama

In the Gintama series they mention a lot of times about Gintoki and his friends are "Yorozuya". What does this mean?

Comment: Without knowing anything about Gintama, yorozuya (万屋) means Jack of all trades.

Comment: Like these ppl make the brand/name of Yorozuya. Like members in a band that make the band what it is.

Comment: Gintama is the name of the series. The person with naturally permed white hair is Sakata Gintoki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yorozuya means Jack of All Trades. Other subs translated Yorozuya into Odd Jobs.

They are called so because they would do any job at all for money. Any jobs ranging from chasing after run away cats to saving the world.